# Match values based on multiple conditions from dataframes of different sizes in R

Tags: r, dataframe, match

I have two dataframes of different sizes. Example:

```
t1 <- data.frame("id"=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,4,5,5,5,6,7,8),"condition"=c(3,3,1,5,5,5,10,10,5,5,2,3,1) )
t2 <- data.frame("ind"=c(1,2,4,5,6,7,8),"test_c"=c(3,5,10,10,2,3,1), "time"=c(32,55,21,34,55,22,19))
```

I would like to match the cases based on two criteria:
`t1$id==t2$ind` and `t1$condition==t2$test_c` and create an additional column in t1 based on the outcome of the variable `t2$time` under these two conditions.

Expected outcome:

```
t3 <- data.frame("id"=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,4,5,5,5,6,7,8),"condition"=c(3,3,1,5,5,5,10,10,5,5,2,3,1) , "time"=c (32,32,NA,55,55,55,21,34,NA,NA,55,22,19))
```

I suspect I should use `merge` or `match` functions but I am not sure which would be the right approach.

Comment: In your expected output, why does `id=1,condition=1` get a time 32? It doesn't match anything in the source frames. FYI, `merge(t1, t2, by.x=c("id","condition"), by.y=c("ind","test_c"), all.x=TRUE)` is a start.

Comment: Apologies for that, see edited output. 32 is meant to be the value of `t2$time` for `t1$id=t2£ind=1` and `t1$condition=te2$test_c=3`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Base R

```r
> out <- merge(t1, t2, by.x=c("id","condition"), by.y=c("ind","test_c"), all.x=TRUE)
> out
   id condition time
1   1         1   NA
2   1         3   32
3   1         3   32
4   2         5   55
5   2         5   55
6   2         5   55
7   4        10   21
8   5         5   NA
9   5         5   NA
10  5        10   34
11  6         2   55
12  7         3   22
13  8         1   19
```

### dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
left_join(t1, t2, by = c("id" = "ind", "condition" = "test_c"))
```

### Differences with your `t3`

There are some differences between them. For the sake of display, I'll show them side-by-side, arranged so that we have an easier comparison.

```r
cbind(out[with(out,order(id,condition)),], t3[with(t3,order(id,condition)),])
#    id condition time id condition time
# 1   1         1   NA  1         1   NA
# 2   1         3   32  1         3   32
# 3   1         3   32  1         3   32
# 4   2         5   55  2         5   55
# 5   2         5   55  2         5   NA
# 6   2         5   55  2         5   NA
# 7   4        10   21  4        10   21
# 8   5         5   NA  5         5   NA
# 9   5         5   NA  5         5   NA
# 10  5        10   34  5        10   34
# 11  6         2   55  6         2   55
# 12  7         3   22  7         3   22
# 13  8         1   19  8         1   19
```

The only differences are with `id=2,condition=5`, where all of them in the `merge` are assigned the same `time=55`, and your `t3` fills only the first of them. I don't think this is a "first only" logic, as there are other repeat `id,condition` that do not elicit the same response. I suspect this is just a mistake with the sample data, or perhaps there is post-`merge` processing you haven't told us yet :-)

Comment: You are right it was just a mistake with the sample data, I'll edit my question, many thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

In case you want to use `match` you can use in addition `interaction` (or `paste`) to use multiple columns.

```
t1$time <- t2[match(interaction(t1), interaction(t2[-3])), 3]
t1
#   id condition time
#1   1         3   32
#2   1         3   32
#3   1         1   NA
#4   2         5   55
#5   2         5   55
#6   2         5   55
#7   4        10   21
#8   5        10   34
#9   5         5   NA
#10  5         5   NA
#11  6         2   55
#12  7         3   22
#13  8         1   19
```